# SQL Server Agent Service deleted

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014, sql-server-agent

Has anybody run into the issue where an application (arcserv) using SQL Server Express 2008 is uninstalled on a server running SQL Server 2014? When arcserv was uninstalled, it or user deleted the SQL Server agent. What was/is the agent recovery process,

1. run the repair from the install media
2. run the install media again
3. uninstall SQL Server and install again

Our efforts to repair ran into multiple issues including registry component keys that we could not access due to missing permissions.

Answer (score 6):

SQL Server 2008 Express shouldn't have a SQL Server Agent, so I'm assuming that the 2014 Agent is what was uninstalled.

I would run a repair from the SQL Server 2014 install media, not the arcserv media.  It's a good idea to make a backup of all of the SQL Server databases in the 2014 instance before doing this.